# .htaccess rewrite GET parameter

Tags: php, .htaccess, get

I would like to change my URL from `site.com/functions/analyze.php?password=test` to `site.com/functions/analyze/password/test`. I am using a .htaccess rewrite rule in attempt to achieve this.

However, upon browsing to my `/functions/analyze/password/test` I can see that the GET parameter being passed is `test.php/password/test` and not `test`.

Where am I going wrong?

```
# Enable editing.
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

# Hide PHP extenstion.
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

# Reroutes for GET.
RewriteRule ^(functions/analyze)/(password)/(.+)$ $1.php?$2=$3 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: Is `functions` a real directory? Does it have a .htaccess?

Comment: @anubhava `functions` is a real directory. `analyze.php` is a real file. Sorry, I'm new to .htaccess... is there supposed to be multiple .htaccess files? Currently, I only have one .htaccess and it sits on the root of my file server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have this rule in root .htaccess with `MultiViews` (content negotiation) turned off:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(functions/analyze)/(password)/(.+)$ $1.php?$2=$3 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: Unfortunately this yields the same result - GET variable results in `test.php/password/test` not `test`.

Comment: Did you add `Options -MultiViews` as suggested? Also show your full .htaccess in question

Comment: I have added my full .htaccess code in my question.

Comment: oh ok, Place this rule after `RewriteEngine On` line

Comment: This works, and I will accept this as the correct answer. Could you explain why this has to be replaced before hiding PHP extensions? Is there a way to place it after hiding PHP extensions?

Comment: Rules have to be placed in a given order otherwise one rule affects other. In this case .php was being added by other rule making this rule ineffective. Best way to debug Apache rules is by using RewriteLog

Comment: Thanks for the help. I guess I'm overlooking Apache configuration as I'm eager to get back to development. Will have to look more into .htaccess writing.

Answer (score 0):

or you can try

```html
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^functions/analyze/password/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ /functions/analyze.php?password=$1
```